# check whether a submit button is clcked through a form that is stored in a variable and excecute in PHP

Tags: php, forms, variables

I wasn't sure if anyone has already posted this kind of problem before.  I am having an issue trying to check whether a submit button has been clicked and that the elements within the associated form have been stored in a variable.

I have a calculator form which displays the results when it is submitted; another form is then displayed dynamically. When the second form is submitted, the results are emailed to me along with person's name and email from the second form. I have to use all PHP as HTML elements and javascript elements will not work without using a PHP variable. Here is a sample of the code:

```
else {
$message0 = "<table style='margin-bottom: 10px; width: 505px;' align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
    <tbody>
        <tr valign='top'>
            <td>
                <div style='padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 245px; height: 58px;'><a href='http://www.manticoretechnology.com/'><img alt='' src='http://stats.manticoretechnology.com/ImgHost/668/20746/logo.png' border='0' height='52' width='379' /></a>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td align='right' valign='bottom'>
                <div style='font-weight: bold; font-size: 9pt; padding-bottom: 5px; text-transform: uppercase; width: 200px; color: #ef762d; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align: right;'>telecom audit <br />challenge</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign='top'>
            <td colspan='2'>
                <div style='margin: 0px; width: 505px; height: 32px; padding: 0px;'><img alt='' src='http://stats.ManticoreTechnology.com/ImgHost/header.gif' height='32' width='505' />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign='top'>
            <td style='border-right: #e9e9e9 1px solid; border-left: #e9e9e9 1px solid;' colspan='2'>
                <div style='font-size: 8pt; background: #ffffff; width: 503px; color: #666666; line-height: 16px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;'>
                    <p style='padding-right: 30px; padding-left: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px; margin: 0px; padding-top: 0px;'>This email has been sent to you because someone has filled out the telecom audit calculator. Details of the activity are as follows:</p>
                    <h2 style='padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 9pt; padding-bottom: 4px; margin: 0px 0px 20px 30px; text-transform: uppercase; width: 75%; color: #14508e; padding-top: 0px; border-bottom: #e9e9e9 1px solid; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;'>Contact Details</h2>
                    <div style='padding-right: 30px; padding-left: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px; margin: 0px; padding-top: 0px;'>
                        <table style='font-size: 8pt; background: #ffffff; color: #666666; line-height: 16px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;'>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style='font-weight: bold;' width='73'>First Name:</td>
                                    <td width='15'></td>
                                    <td width='111'>$fname</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style='font-weight: bold;'>Last Name:</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>$lname</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style='font-weight: bold;'>Email:</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>$email</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style='font-weight: bold;'></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style='font-weight: bold;'>Landline:</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>\$ $landline</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style='font-weight: bold;'>Long Distance:</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>\$ $longdist</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style='font-weight: bold;'>Wireless:</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>\$ $wireless</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style='font-weight: bold;'>Data:</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>\$ $data</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style='font-weight: bold;'>Conferencing:</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>\$ $conference</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style='font-weight: bold;'></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style='font-weight: bold;'></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style='font-weight: bold;'><strong>Total Telecom Expense Per Month:</strong>
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>\$ $results</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style='font-weight: bold;'><strong>Total Telecom Expense Per Year:</strong>
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>\$ $yresults</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style='font-weight: bold;'><strong>Estimated Savings:</strong>
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>\$ $sevenpercent</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign='top'>
            <td colspan='2'>
                <div style='margin: 0px; width: 505px; height: 32px; padding: 0px;'><img alt='' src='http://stats.ManticoreTechnology.com/ImgHost/footer.gif' height='30' width='505' />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<center>
    <div style='margin: 0px auto; width: 504px; text-align: left;'>
        <p style='padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px; font-size: 7pt; padding-bottom: 20px; margin: 0px; color: #999999; padding-top: 0px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;'>ISI Telemanagement Solutions, Inc., 1051 Perimeter Drive, Suite 200., Schaumburg, IL, 60173, 847-995-0002<br /> This email has been sent to you as part of your Manticore Technology account. Please see your account administrator if you have any questions, or contact your Manticore account representative.</p>
    </div>
</center>";
$formoutput = "<form id='$adminform' class='form-validate' enctype='multipart/form-data' onsubmit='return true' name='$adminform' method='post' action='#' novalidate='novalidate'>
<table width='250px' align='center'>
<tr>
<td class='firstrow_dti' width='39%' align='left'>First Name</td><td class='firstrow_dti' width='14%' align='left'></td>
<td class='firstrow_dti' width='35%' align='left'>Last Name</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='firstrow_dti' width='4%' align='left'>
<input id='fld_18' class='elem18 ' type='text' placeholder='' mask='' value='' name='fld_18' fldname='fname'>
</td>
<td class='firstrow_dti' width='39%' align='left'></td>
<td class='firstrow_dti' width='14%' align='left'>
<input id='fld_19' class='elem19 ' type='text' placeholder='' mask='' value='' name='fld_19' fldname='lname'>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='firstrow_dti' width='4%' align='left'></td>
<td class='firstrow_dti' width='39%' height='5' align='left'></td>
<td class='firstrow_dti' width='14%' align='left'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='firstrow_dti' align='left'>Email</td>
<td class='firstrow_dti' width='39%' align='left'></td>
<td class='firstrow_dti' width='14%' align='left'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='firstrow_dti' width='4%' align='left'>
<input id='fld_16' class='required elem16 valid' type='text' placeholder='' mask='' value='' name='fld_16' fldname='email'>
</td>
<td class='firstrow_dti' width='39%' align='left'></td>
<td class='firstrow_dti' width='14%' align='left'></td>
</tr>
</table>
<div class='row-fluid2' align='center'>
<div class='btcalctoolbar span12'>
<input id='$submitbutton' class='btn btn-primary' type='button' value='Submit' name='submit'>
<input type='hidden' value='1' name='submitted' />
<input type='hidden' value='' name='postSection'>
<input type='hidden' value='' name='postSection2'>
<input class='btn' type='reset' value='Reset' onclick='javascript:reset$resetbutton;return true;'>
</div>
</div>
</form>";
    $qualify = "<table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
<tr>
<td width='30%' valign='top' align='center'><img width='150' height='150' alt='' style='padding-top:100px;' src='/images/badge/congrats-badge.png'></td>
<td width='70%' valign='top' mc:edit='small-image-left-text'>
<p style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#284C85; font-size:16px; line-height:18px; padding-top:35px;margin-right:45px;'>Congratulations!</p>
<p style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#333; font-size:12px;color:#333;line-height:18px;margin-right:45px;'>After calculating your telecom needs, we are happy to say that you qualify for our Telecom Savings Challenge.</p>
<p style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#333; font-size:12px;color:#333;line-height:18px;margin-right:45px;'>If we can't save you <strong style='font-size:13px;'>" . "$" . $sevenpercent . "</strong>, then you'll get a <strong style='font-size:13px;'>$100 gift card</strong>. No Strings attached.</p>
<p><!-- START MODULE - 3 columns -->
<table width='530' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' align='center'>
<tr>
<td width='160' valign='top' align='center'><img src='http://www.isi-info.com/m/campaign/telecom-savings/telecom-challenge-accepted/images/Number-icon-set-1.png' width='32' height='32' /><br><p style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#333; font-size:12px;color:#333;line-height:18px'>Download and sign <br/>the attached NDA</p><img src='http://www.isi-info.com/m/campaign/telecom-savings/telecom-challenge-accepted/images/download-button.png' width='89' height='23' /></td>


<td width='25' align='center' valign='top'><img src='http://www.isi-info.com/m/assets/divider/content-divider-normal-90-grey.jpg' width='10' height='115'/></td>


<td width='160' valign='top' align='center'><img src='http://www.isi-info.com/m/campaign/telecom-savings/telecom-challenge-accepted/images/Number-icon-set-2.png' width='32' height='32' /><br><p style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#333;font-size:12px;color:#000000;line-height:18px'>Send us your <br/>telecom invoices</p><img src='http://www.isi-info.com/m/campaign/telecom-savings/telecom-challenge-accepted/images/email-button.png' width='89' height='23' /></td>


<td width='25' align='center' valign='top'><img src='http://www.isi-info.com/m/assets/divider/content-divider-normal-90-grey.jpg' width='10' height='115'/></td>


<td width='160' valign='top' align='center'><img src='http://www.isi-info.com/m/campaign/telecom-savings/telecom-challenge-accepted/images/Number-icon-set-3.png' width='32' height='32' /><br><p style='color:#333; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#000000;line-height:18px'>We'll review your invoices and provide you with a report</p></td>
</tr>
</table>
<!-- END MODULE - 3 columns --></p>
<p style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#333; font-size:12px;color:#333;line-height:18px;margin-right:45px;'>So what happens next? Check your registered email for an update on the next step. Basically, after signing a mutual NDA, we will need to review invoices from your most recent full month of billing.</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
$formoutput
<div>
</div>
";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $to2 = "email@email.com";
    $subject2 = "subject"; 
    mail($to2, $subject2, $message0, $headers);
}
else {
echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
alert('email failed');
</script>";
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Putting the form in a variable is irrelevant. Once you echo it, it doesn't matter where it came from. But I don't see you echoing the form anywhere.

Comment: Post all your code, starting with `else` only shows half the story

Comment: the form is stored in a variable called $formoutput.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?  1. Form submit.  2. Another form submit. 3. Email you the results?

Comment: Also, I don't think it matters previous to the else statement in this case.

Comment: Have the second form which is displayed dynamically through a variable and then using that form to email out some results along with the information provided in the second form.

Comment: I'm realizing that I may need to use AJAX and then apply it on to the onclick within the input button. That may be the best solution?

Comment: I actually figured out. I had to use AJAX and create an external PHP file to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you need to have code to receive the form input - which I see you are sending via POST.

Once the form is submitted, all the details entered in the form fields will be in POST variables (i.e. anything entered in the fld_18 input will be found in $_POST['fld_18'].)

Are you looking for the page to reload? Or are you sending the user to another page after form submission?

If you want to display the second form without reload or sending the user to another page, utilizing JQuery may be more helpful to you.

Comment: I guess I should clarify that the first form displayed the html output on the same page, which also displays a second form. I am having trouble getting the second form to email out anything from the submit button without having to reload or send them to another page.

Comment: Also the isset() is not reading the second form button when clicked. unless I am doing something wrong. and I cannot put the if statement in the variable.

Comment: Are you using the same submit button for both forms?

Comment: No, they are different.

Comment: I ask because in the code snipped you've provided, there is only one submit button. I am guessing they have different names?

Comment: Yes, the first one is the calculate button which calculates the numbers in a form and then displays them on the same page. This  second button when clicked just emails the results out as a notification with their name and email provided from this second form.

Comment: Without seeing all the code it's hard to tell. Clearly the $_POST['submit'] isn't getting set somehow. I notice this code is wrapped in an else{} - I wonder if it's a scope issue somehow.

Comment: Because I have the first form displays two different things depending on what the calculations come out to, hence why the if/else statement. The other part has no second form.

Comment: At this point, I'm not sure what else to try - I would definitely use FireBug or something similar to check the POST variables after the submit button is pressed. If the POST variable is not being passed, then you'll have to reevaluate your form action...

Is there a way to view the page you're working on? i.e. what URL is it?

Comment: I think I know why the isset() isn't working as I think when the first form button is clicked and goes through the else statement, the isset() function is executed before having the second form button the chance of being clicked, thus always returning false and in theory if the if statement with the isset() function was placed that variable maybe it would read it, but how would I be able to get it working?

Comment: Also, the page is on a development server which is not accessible to the public.

Comment: Yes - upon first load of the page, the POST variable would not be set. I guess I was assuming that after the first form button is clicked, the page is reloaded with the POST variable passed.

Maybe I'm still unclear on how the second form is being displayed. After the first submit button is clicked - <input id='$submitbutton' class='btn btn-primary' type='button' value='Submit' name='submit'>
- what is the value of $submitbutton?

Comment: It is based off of the first button which is a random number plus submit, which would be something like 1234_submit as the id. The first button would be something like 1234_calculate.